# Using Guzzle's Promise library when does PHP exit

Tags: php, promise, guzzle

In JS, promises make sense because the application is always in memory and you want things to occur without blocking execution (at least in the case of JS running in a browser).

But in PHP when your code runs and completes PHP exit's. So in the instance where you use Guzzle promises, does:

1. a unresolved/unrejected) promise callback still get run somehow after PHP exit's (seems unlikely)?, or
2. if the execution flow has reached the end of the non-promised code, does it wait for all promises to resolve before exiting, even without a `$fooPromise->wait()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a unresolved/unrejected) promise callback still get run somehow after PHP exit's (seems unlikely)?

No, it doesn't.

> if the execution flow has reached the end of the non-promised code, does it wait for all promises to resolve before exiting, even without a $fooPromise->wait() call?

No, it doesn't wait for promises, unless `->wait()` is explicitly called.

Guzzle promises are there mostly to do many HTTP queries in parallel. Sometimes you need to do that even inside one request from a user (browser).